# How can I add an value to an input type

Tags: javascript, variables

How can I add an value to an input type.

I'm currently working on a converter for meter to kilometer, to mile, ...

I've created different input types in my HTML Code and took the value of them in JS, which worked completely fine, and I prevented the page from reloading after I click submit. Now I want to reassign the new, calculated value (kilometer.value = meter / 1000), but this doesn't work.

It works completely fine, when I'm putting an console.log after the variable meter and the first variable kilometer. It logs the correct number - the reassignment just doesn't work.

JavaScript:

```
const calculateMeter = () => {
    let meter = document.getElementById("meter").value;

    let kilometer = document.getElementById("kilometer").value;
    kilometer.value = meter / 1000;
}
```

HTML:

```
<form id="calculator" onsubmit="calculateMeter(); return false">
    <label for="kilometer">Kilometer:</label>
    <input type="number" id="kilometer"><br>

    <label for="meter">Meter:</label>
    <input type="number" id="meter"><br>
```

Comment: parse `document.getElementById("meter").value` to integer or float. [parseFloat](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/parseFloat), [parseInt](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/parseInt)

Comment: `kilometer` is the *`value`* of the element; it does not itself have a `value` property.

Comment: You store a string - from the value property of the element - into the variable, but then try to set the value property of that value to another value. The problem is that `kilometer` is a string, not an element.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`value` of `<input>` is always a string, but in case of numerical input types, like `type="number"`, or `type="range"`, you can get the number directly using `valueAsNumber`:

```js
const calculateMeter = () => {
  let kilometer = document.getElementById("kilometer").valueAsNumber;
  document.getElementById("meter").value = kilometer * 1000;
}

const calculateKilometer = () => {
  let meter = document.getElementById("meter").valueAsNumber;
  document.getElementById("kilometer").value = meter / 1000;
}
```

```html
  <label for="kilometer">Kilometer:</label>
  <input type="number" id="kilometer" oninput="calculateMeter()"><br>

  <label for="meter">Meter:</label>
  <input type="number" id="meter" oninput="calculateKilometer()"><br>
```

Answer (score 1):

Did you mean something like, that?

```js
let meterInp = document.getElementById("meter");
let kilometerInp = document.getElementById("kilometer");

meterInp.addEventListener("change", ()=>{
  kilometerInp.value = (+meterInp.value)/1000;
});
kilometerInp.addEventListener("change", ()=>{
  meterInp.value = (+kilometerInp.value)*1000;
});
```

```html
<form id="calculator" onsubmit="calculateMeter(); return false">
    <label for="kilometer">Kilometer:</label>
    <input type="number" id="kilometer" step="0.00001"><br>

    <label for="meter">Meter:</label>
    <input type="number" step="0.01" id="meter"><br>
</form>
```

The (+) converts string to number.
for e.g. (+meterInp.value)/1000

Answer (score 0):

You should convert **meter** to `intiger`

```
const calculateMeter = () => {
    let meter = document.getElementById("meter").value;

    let kilometer = document.getElementById("kilometer").value;
    kilometer.value = Number(meter) / 1000;
}
```